# Why does this error appear to me? When applying randomTrips for SUMO.. Please is there any idea..?

Tags: sumo

**I need help!!!!
Why does this error appear to me? When applying randomTrips for SUMO..
Please is there any help?**

N:\Thesis\SUMO\SUMO map>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\randomTrips.py" -n map.net.xml -r map.rou.xml -o trips.xml -e 600 -p 0.5

randomTrips.py: error: the following arguments are required: -n/--net-file

[Illustrative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4MSR.png)

Comment: Please add at least the call you are doing and do not post screenshots rather copy input and output into your question. Did you specify the net file with `-n`?

Comment: Thank you..
Edited.. I hope to get an answer because I urgently need it.

Comment: That looks indeed strange. The map.net.xml file is there? Which SUMO version is this? Could you retry in a folder which does not have a space in its name?

Comment: Yes, it is very confusing!!
I tried all possible ways and made sure that the writing was correct and that the files existed, but I don't know why this error was... I was hoping to find someone here to help me with a solution.

Comment: Can you say which SUMO and which python version you use and post a list of files in the directory (the output of `dir`)

Comment: SUMO version: 1.14.0 and python version:3.10, list of files in the directory: map.osm, map.net.xml, polygons.xml, typemap.xml

Comment: no idea, you could try again in a folder which does not have a space in its name but I doubt it is the reason. Does osmWebWizard work?